# getElementById inside the vue js mounted life cycle hooks results in null

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've been getting `null` when I try to see what's inside an id with `document.getElementById`. Part of the code is below:

```
<input-layout v-if="edit" label="Status" class="grayout">
        <u-select v-model='test.status' :options="testStatus" tabindex="14" class="grayout" id="testStatusDropDown"/>
</input-layout>

<input id="input1" type="checkbox">
```

Note that, `v-if="edit"` results in true.

In the `mounted` life cycle hook I have:

```
mounted () {
      this.$nextTick(function (){
      console.log(document.getElementById("input1"))
      console.log(document.getElementById("testStatusDropDown"))
    })
  },
```

Originally I didn't have the `console.log` statements in the mounted method which resulted in `null` for both `input1` and `testStatusDropDown`. I understand that because both elements do not exist yet when that part of the code runs. So then I moved them into the mounted method, now, I can see `<input id="input1" type="checkbox">` but for the second log statement I get `null`.

I went to the vue js mounted api docs, which can be found here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted. From what I can see is that `mounted` does not guarantee all child components have been mounted so I need to use `this.$nextTic` inside the `mounted` method. However, even after adding `this.$nextTick` I'm still having the same issue where `document.getElementById("testStatusDropDown")` results in `null` when I expect it to be `<u-select v-model='test.status' :options="testStatus" tabindex="14" class="grayout" id="testStatusDropDown"/>`.

Is my expectation incorrect? What do I need to change such that `document.getElementById("testStatusDropDown")` does not return `null`?

Comment: Have you used `ref` to access the element?

Comment: `<input id="input1" ref="input1" type="checkbox">` and in mounted `this.$refs.input1`

Comment: No I have not, my vue knowledge is limited, could you expand a little more?

Comment: It is used to reference an element in vue 
https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref

Comment: You dont really need getElementById when you are using v-model

Comment: @MAY, that worked for me, I'll read more into it. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use ref to reference an element in vuejs.

```
<input id="input1" ref="input1" type="checkbox">
```

and in mounted access it using:

```
this.$refs.input1
```